# Spring batch check running Job Instance

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-job-monitoring

I was trying to check if there is any running instance of the job.

```
Set<JobExecution> jobExecutions = jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions(job.getName());
```

But the above code is not working when we have older executions that didn't finish correctly.
In that case the size of jobExecutions is more than 1.

Comment: Well, it seems to me it's doing its job. probably you should implement JobExecutionListener to see if the job is finished executing for example

Comment: Yes @Karim technically you are correct. But I donot want to consider the one which didnot finish correctly. Is there any better ways of managing it?

Comment: @Arindam: I have provided an answer & can tweak it provided you explain more as what you mean by - **older executions that didn't finish correctly**.

Answer (score 2):

I looked into Spring Batch code to see what executions this method is fetching & below is the query that I found in source code.

```
private static final String GET_RUNNING_EXECUTIONS = "SELECT E.JOB_EXECUTION_ID, E.START_TIME, E.END_TIME, E.STATUS, E.EXIT_CODE, E.EXIT_MESSAGE, E.CREATE_TIME, E.LAST_UPDATED, E.VERSION, "
            + "E.JOB_INSTANCE_ID, E.JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION from %PREFIX%JOB_EXECUTION E, %PREFIX%JOB_INSTANCE I where E.JOB_INSTANCE_ID=I.JOB_INSTANCE_ID and I.JOB_NAME=? and E.END_TIME is NULL order by E.JOB_EXECUTION_ID desc";
```

So as you see in above query, there is only one criteria - `END_TIME is NULL` from Job Execution table. So it wouldn't matter as when execution completed - it would give you all executions where END_TIME is not populated.

You can simply do a Java filtering on desired executions that you need as per your business need like ,

`Set<JobExecution> runningJobExecutions = jobExecutions.stream().filter(jobExecution->ExitStatus.COMPLETED.equals(jobExecution.getExitStatus())).collect(Collectors.toSet());`

You can modify `filter` method as per your need.